# some kernel address is not mapped for arm64bit

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I run command and found this kernel address is not mapped.
Can anyone help me to understand what might be the reason for it?

#cat /sys/kernel/debug/kernel_page_tables

This address range is not mapped.
0xffffffc0db800000-0xffffffc0db825000 is not mapped.

```
Output of kernel_page_tables.
(initramfs) cat /sys/kernel/debug/kernel_page_tables
---[ vmalloc() Area ]---
0xffffff8000000000-0xffffff8000001000           4K     RW NX     AF    UXN DEVICE/nGnRE
0xffffff8000002000-0xffffff8000003000           4K     RW NX     AF    UXN DEVICE/nGnRE
0xffffff8000006000-0xffffff8000007000           4K     RW NX     AF    UXN DEVICE/nGnRE
0xffffff800000a000-0xffffff800000b000           4K     RW NX     AF    UXN DEVICE/nGnRE
0xffffff8000030000-0xffffff8000070000         256K     RW NX SHD AF    UXN MEM/BUFFERABLE
0xffffff8000072000-0xffffff8000073000           4K     RW NX     AF    UXN DEVICE/nGnRE
0xffffff8000074000-0xffffff8000075000           4K     RW NX     AF    UXN DEVICE/nGnRE
0xffffff8000076000-0xffffff8000077000           4K     RW NX     AF    UXN DEVICE/nGnRE
0xffffff8000078000-0xffffff8000079000           4K     RW NX     AF    UXN DEVICE/nGnRE
0xffffff800007a000-0xffffff800007b000           4K     RW NX     AF    UXN DEVICE/nGnRE
0xffffff800007c000-0xffffff800007d000           4K     RW NX     AF    UXN DEVICE/nGnRE
0xffffff800007e000-0xffffff800007f000           4K     RW NX     AF    UXN DEVICE/nGnRE
0xffffff8000080000-0xffffff8000085000          20K     RW NX     AF    UXN DEVICE/nGnRE
0xffffff8000086000-0xffffff8000087000           4K     RW NX     AF    UXN DEVICE/nGnRE
0xffffff8000088000-0xffffff800008c000          16K     RW NX     AF    UXN DEVICE/
0xffffffbbfffce000-0xffffffbbfffd3000          20K     RW NX SHD AF    UXN MEM/NORMAL
0xffffffbbfffdf000-0xffffffbbfffe4000          20K     RW NX SHD AF    UXN MEM/NORMAL
....
---[ vmalloc() End ]---
0xffffffbc00000000-0xffffffbc0a000000         160M RW x  SHD AF    MEM/NORMAL
---[ Modules ]---
---[ Kernel Mapping ]---
0xffffffc000000000-0xffffffc000200000           2M RW NX SHD AF    MEM/NORMAL
0xffffffc000200000-0xffffffc000e00000          12M ro x  SHD AF    MEM/NORMAL
0xffffffc000e00000-0xffffffc001400000           6M ro NX SHD AF    MEM/NORMAL
0xffffffc001400000-0xffffffc001600000           2M ro x  SHD AF    MEM/NORMAL
0xffffffc001600000-0xffffffc003400000          30M RW NX SHD AF    MEM/NORMAL
0xffffffc003400000-0xffffffc005800000          36M     RW NX SHD AF    UXN MEM/NORMAL
0xffffffc005800000-0xffffffc006200000          10M RW NX SHD AF    MEM/NORMAL
0xffffffc006200000-0xffffffc006300000           1M     RW NX SHD AF    UXN MEM/NORMAL
0xffffffc00e700000-0xffffffc00e800000           1M     RW NX SHD AF    UXN MEM/NORMAL
0xffffffc00e800000-0xffffffc0db400000        3276M RW NX SHD AF    MEM/NORMAL
0xffffffc0db400000-0xffffffc0db800000           4M     RW NX SHD AF    UXN  MEM/NORMAL                                                                                   ------------- "148K is not mapped" ----------------------------------------
0xffffffc0db825000-0xffffffc0f8000000      466796K     RW NX SHD AF    UXN MEM/NORMAL
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: as you see in kernel mapping section minimum size of section is 1 MB, but size between  address range  0xffffffc0db800000-0xffffffc0db825000 is some where is  148kb , then you know what I mean ?

Comment: Thank you, can you please explain in detail